# Shorten url with GET parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My Current url string is as follows :

`domain.com/search.php?s1=p1&s2=p2&s3=p3`

I want to convert the same to :

`domain.com/search/p1/p2/p3`

Let me know what changes/rules do i need to write in my .htaccess for the same

Also, i m not using any framework, its in core PHP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?s1=$1&s2=$2&s3=$3 [L,QSA]
```